# Not able to ssh over tor

Tags: onion-services, torsocks, ssh, torify

I did setup and V3 hidden service for ssh but I'm not able to connect to the server through tor. When I run `torify ssh USER@MYHIDDENSERVICEADDRESS.onion`I get the following error:

```
1639811611 ERROR torsocks[44305]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)
ssh: connect to host MYHIDDENSERVICEADDRESS.onion port 22: Connection refused
```

I don't know why it's not working. I added the authentication file to `var/lib/tor/hidden_service_ssh/USER/authorized_clients` and also configured `/var/lib/tor/onion_auth` according to [this guide](https://matt.traudt.xyz/posts/creating-private-v3-FgbdRTFr/) (which worked for another hidden service).

I read somewhere that torsocks is depreciated since hidden service V3 but I'm not sure how to deal with it if that is the case.

Comment: Did you make sure that the SSH service is running on your hidden host ? Is the firewall set up to allow connections to port 22 ?

Comment: Try to setup plain hidden service first - without client authorization. When you have this working - add the client authorization.

Comment: @Anonymous yes, it is running and the firewall is properly setup. I checked again

Comment: @Tomek The thing is, that the authorization works, but only in the tor browser. When I go to the .onion-site I am asked to enter the private key.
However I don't want to enter the private key manually. So I set up the client authorization by adding the private key (with descriptor etc) in `/var/lib/tor/onion_auth/` on my local machine. But when I try to restart tor, I get the error above. So the .onion-service works but I don't get the `ClientOnionAuthDir` running...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the ssh proxycommand instead of torify:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='nc -x 127.0.0.1:9150 %h %p' user@hiddenservice
```

Answer (score 0):

The only **right&true** way to solve this is to use Tor's on-flight host mappings and `TransPort` embedded in your firewall rules. It will fix not just SSH and SCP, but will aid literally any regular tool you'll use. Try it - and feel free to ask if you need more help!